# Postgres Arrays Rows aggregation

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregation

I have a recursive query in which i m getting rows of arrays as shown below. How could I possible merge all rows into one array in one row and removing duplicates? Ordering is not important.

```
--my_column--
"{431}"
"{431,33}"
"{431,60}"
"{431,28}"
"{431,1}"
"{431,226}"
"{431,38}"
"{431,226,229}"
"{431,226,227}"
"{431,226,235}"
"{431,226,239}"
"{431,226,241}"
```

I tried the query below but I am getting one empty integer [] column

```
select array(select unnest(my_column) from my_table
```

thanks

Comment: There are no duplicates in your list.  What results do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_agg()` with `distinct` and (not necessary) `order by` from `unnest()`:

```
with my_table(my_column) as (
values
    ('{431}'::int[]),
    ('{431,33}'),
    ('{431,60}'),
    ('{431,28}'),
    ('{431,1}'),
    ('{431,226}'),
    ('{431,38}'),
    ('{431,226,229}'),
    ('{431,226,227}'),
    ('{431,226,235}'),
    ('{431,226,239}'),
    ('{431,226,241}')
)

select array_agg(distinct elem order by elem)
from my_table,
lateral unnest(my_column) elem;

                  array_agg                  
---------------------------------------------
 {1,28,33,38,60,226,227,229,235,239,241,431}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without [lateral subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
select array_agg(distinct val) from
  (select unnest(my_column) as val from my_table) x;
```